# c# ListView - got "the path is not a legal form" while implementing MouseDoubleClick() method

Tags: c#, listview, double-click

I'm very new to C#. I'm populating a File Explorer using C#. What i want to do now is implementing the `listView1_MouseDoubleClick()` method so that when I double-click in a sub folder, the current listView will be cleared then it will display files and folders in that subfolders (like what Windows Explorer does). Here's my code:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listView1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    string path = listView1.Items[i].Name;
                    comboBox1.Text = path;
                    listView1.Items.Clear();
                    LoadFilesAndDir(path);
                }
            }
        }

    private void LoadFilesAndDir(string address)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(address);
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(fi.Name);
            }
            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo listd in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(listd.FullName, listd.Name, 0);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
        }
    }
```

But it failed to run. When I debug this error step by step, I found out that after this statement: `path = listView1.Items[i].Name;` the `path` variable's value is `""`. So i guess that the reason which let to the error. But I don't know how to fix that... Could you guys help me with this ? Thanks a lot in advanced !

Comment: Use the Text property, not the Name property.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare the string 'path' first

```
string path = "";
```

Then insert this code:

```
private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                path = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items[i]);
                // This replaces the part "List View Item: {"
                path = path.Replace("ListViewItem: {", "");
                // This replaces the part "}"
                path = path.Replace("}", "");
                comboBox1.Text = path;
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                LoadFilesAndDir(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is a bit long, but it works!

Comment: The path can get the label of the folder now, for example: path = "GAMES". But i think that's not enough information for the next method LoadFilesAndDir(path) to run :(

Comment: Don't do that. `ListViewItem` has a `Text` property.